# How do i get all rows with max value in laravel eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a table in my db that looks like this:

| Col 1 | Col 2 |
| --- | --- |
| John | 230601 |
| Frank | 230601 |
| Tom | 230604 |
| Bill | 230604 |
| Tina | 230604 |
| Leroy | 230602 |
| Ernie | 230601 |
| Sue | 230601 |

I want to get all rows with the max col2 value. (in this case max value is 230604 and it would be Tom, Bill and Tina).

I tried the below which failed:

```
$data = DB::table($table)->where('col2','=','(SELECT max(col2) from '.$table.')')->get($fields);
```

Comment: I think two queries (one for max value, one for select) will be ok. Optimization is good when its really need :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do

```
$maxValue = DB::table($table)->max('col2');
$data = DB::table($table)->where('col2', $maxValue)->get($fields);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Model::max("col2");`